# .pdb file isn't being recognized and it was just built

Tags: visual-studio-2013

For some reason that I cannot fathom, the `.pdb` file for a solution that has a single project is not being recognized, even after it is just built. Looking at the loaded modules, I can see that it found attempted to load it, but it says `PDB does not match image.` The executable and the `.pdb` file also have the same date time stamp.

Just for reference and if it matters, this is a BCG demo file (RibbonMDIDemo) and I loaded it through the `.vxproj` file, which it then converted to a `.sln` file.  I then slightly modified it to try something out.

Does anyone have any idea why this may not be working?  What would cause a just build `.pdb` file not to match the image it also just built?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding?

Comment: Tried that a few times.  No joy. :(